# Lexical analysis for assignment in a POSIX shell

Tags: shell, posix, assignment

For the lexical analysis in a POSIX shell, from  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

> **7.  [Assignment preceding command name]**
>
> **a.  [When the first word]**
>
> If the TOKEN does not contain the character ’=’, rule 1 is applied.
>   Otherwise, 7b shall be applied.
>
> **b.  [Not the first word]**
>
> If the TOKEN contains the  character:
>
> — If it begins with ’=’, the token WORD shall be returned.
>
> — If all  the  characters  preceding ’=’ form  a  valid  name  (see 
>   XBD Section
>   3.231),  the  token ASSIGNMENT_WORD shall  be  returned.  (Quoted characters cannot participate in forming a valid name.)
>
> — Otherwise, it is unspecified whether it is ASSIGNMENT_WORD or WORD
>   that is returned. Assignment to the NAME shall occur as specified in
>   Section 2.9.1.

1. What does 'the first word' mean?

   What case is 'When the first word'?

   What case is 'Not the first word'?
2. 'When the first word', What case is 'If the TOKEN does not
   contain the character ’=’'?
3. When 'Not the first word',

   - What case is 'If it begins with ’=’'?
   - What case is 'Otherwise'?

Comment: I'm puzzled by the silent downvotes. Formal grammar rules are certainly hard to understand and POSIX is definitely on topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What does 'the first word' mean?

The first token that is not an operand.

> What case is 'When the first word'?

When the first token that is not an operand is analyzed.

> What case is 'Not the first word'?

This case is used to allow the processing of multiple assignments present in the same line.

> 2. 'When the first word', What case is 'If the TOKEN does not contain the character ’=’'?

When the first token that is not an operand doesn't contain an `=` sign, this is not an assignment and so it will be processed as a command name (rule 1).

> 3. When 'Not the first word',
>
>    - What case is 'If it begins with ’=’'?

That would be something like:

```
=123
```

> - What case is 'Otherwise'?

There are two 'otherwise', the first one would be something like:

```
invalid%variable+name=123
```

the second 'otherwise' covers the cases where a word that is not the first one doesn't contain an assignment.